# Trying to plot a bar chart with age categories issue. Seaborn and Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

HI all I have the following groups of data:

```
sumcosts = df.groupby('AgeGroup').Costs.sum()
print(sumcosts):
AgeGroup
18-25      536295.37
25-35     1784085.88
35-45     2395250.62
45-55     5483060.33
55-65    11652094.30
65-75     9633490.63
75+       5186867.32
Name: Costs, dtype: float64

countoftrips = df.groupby('AgeGroup').Booking.nunique()

print(countoftrips):
AgeGroup
18-25     139
25-35     398
35-45     379
45-55     738
55-65    1417
65-75     995
75+       545
Name: Booking, dtype: int64
```

When trying to plot these i have used the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(data=sumcosts, palette="rocket", ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=countoftrips, palette="rocket", ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

the output is this:

[image]

The line section looks correct but the bar chart has obviously stoppoed in the first age bracket. Any ideas on how to correct? I tried to define the `x='Agegroup' and y='Costs'` but then got errors and this is the most progress I can get to. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your barplot appears to be showing the sum of *all* costs, not just those of the 18-25 age group. The fact this bar is appearing under the x-axis label for the 18-25 group is only b/c of the positioning of your axis for the line plot - which makes it confusing.

> I created a dummy data set of 1000 rows in a .csv to graph this
>   example, but my values are different - so the plots will look visually
>   different, everything else will work the same for you.

### Jupyter Notebook Setup:

(*images added to reflect outputs*)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

%matplotlib inline

# Read in dataset 'df', showing the header
df = pd.read_csv('./data-raw.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

Assuming you have no NaN values in your data ... otherwise you can use `dropna()` to remove them.

```
# Check if there are any NaN values in the all_stocks dataframe
print('Number of NaN values in the columns of our DataFrame:\n', df.isnull().sum())

# Remove any rows that contain NaN values using dropna (as applicable) 
data.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
```

[image]

Your `sumcosts` and `countoftrips` are **not** a requirement for creating your plots, and I believe are the cause of your plotting error for the bar graph.  I've included them here, but **are not** using them when creating the plot.

[image]

#### Plot Type:

It is also important to keep in mind that a bar plot shows only the mean (or other estimator, i.e std) value, but in many cases, it may be more informative to show the distribution of values at each level of the categorical variables. In that case, other approaches such as a [box or violin plot may be more appropriate.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

### Solution:

This is assuming you want to have the line and bar plot layered over each other, as in your example:

```
# This plot has both graphs on the axis you outlined in your code, 
# I used the ci = None parameter to remove the confidence intervals to
# make the combined plot easier to read (optional)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sb.barplot(data = df, x = 'AgeGroup', y = 'Costs', ci = None,
                      ax = ax1, palette = 'rocket', order = ['18-25', 
                      '25-35','35-45','45-55','55-65', '65-75', '75+']);

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sb.lineplot(data = df, x = 'AgeGroup', y = 'Booking', ax = ax2, ci = None);
plt.xlabel('Age Group Ranges');
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is an alternative you could try, also using `subplot`, but separating the two plots.

```
# Adjusting the plot size just to make it easier to read here:
plt.figure(figsize = [14, 4])

#Bar Chart on Left
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) # 1 row, 2 cols, subplot 1
sb.barplot(data = df, x = 'AgeGroup', y = 'Costs', palette = 'rocket',
           ci = 'sd', order = ['18-25', '25-35', '35-45',
                        '45-55','55-65', '65-75', '75+']);
plt.xlabel('Age Group Ranges')
plt.ylabel('Costs')

# Line Chart on Right
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) # 1 row, 2 cols, subplot 2
sb.lineplot(data = df, x = 'AgeGroup', y = 'Booking', ci = None)
plt.xlabel('Age Group Ranges')
plt.ylabel('Bookings');
```

[image]

Hope you find helpful!

Comment: Thanks @jwho. This is fantastic and thanks for your detail. I am going to try your solution out now so will let you know how i go!